# Tell GULP to use different layout files for different domain paths

Tags: node.js, gulp

Using this code on my node.js Server

```
// Copy page templates into finished HTML files
function pages() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.{html,hbs,handlebars}')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      data: 'src/data/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist));
}
```

It works great for the pages - where f.e. start.html in src/pages/DE is used on mydomain.de/DE/start.html and start.html in src/pages/EN is used on mydomain.de/EN/start.html

But for the layouts where I need to specify things like language this wont work.
There are also two folders - src/layouts/DE and src/layouts/EN both contain a default.html file.
But no matter which domain-path I choose, the build system always use the file in the EN path.
Any suggests?

Answer (score 0):

The following do the job

```
// Copy page templates into finished HTML files
function pages() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.{html,hbs,handlebars}')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      data: 'src/data/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/',
      pageLayouts: {
        'DE': 'DE',
        'EN': 'EN',
  }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist));
}
```

Just add the pageLayouts which means the all pages in src/pages/DE should use the FILE !!! src/layouts/DE.html - same for the EN. There is no need for subfolders in layouts.